# How can I enable pretty-printing in Chrome manually?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, json

There are some great Chrome extensions around for pretty-printing JSON (great SU question here: [Google Chrome Plugin for JSON Reading](https://superuser.com/questions/72800/google-chrome-plugin-for-json-reading)), but they all seem to depend on detecting whether the incoming document is in a JSON format automagically.

Knowing that, the question is: How can I set it up so that I can pretty-print displayed JSON manually, rather than relying on some extension's magical detection (that may or may not fail to trigger when I need it to)?

I started from that SU post, and found some extensions:

- [JSONVue](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonvue/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
- [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa)

(i.e., the results for JSON formatter). Those, and more, will all detect JSON formatting, and display it in a pretty-printed way, but none of them support an easy, bugproof way to manually turn it on on a page where JSON is not detected (except by, perhaps, tricking the engine by sticking format=json in the query string, but none of them were explicit about telling me I could do that).

Is there a better option out there?

Comment: We don't do product recommendations unless prior research is shown (http://superuser.com/faq). please list the tools you have tried.  I'd need to flag this as not useful. If you turn your question into "How can I do X?" it likely won't be deleted. Act now.

Comment: From the closing: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

It seems like the question, "Is there a plugin that allows pretty-printing to manually be enabled" is pretty straightforward, and easy to support with reference. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your question was reopened.

Comment: Guess the accepted answer should just be "yes" then :P

Comment: That would make sense if the question didn't start with "How", but it does start that way, so I don't understand your reasoning.

Answer (score 21):

[JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa) provides buttons to toggle between raw and formatted views of a JSON document.

It is [open source](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter). As of March 2023, the chrome extension was last updated on January 2023 and the last commit was in March 2023.

---

*As of November 2016, the last commit was in March 2015. There are over 100 [forks](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter/network), many of which have more recent commits. It's not immediately clear if one of those forks is better maintained.*

---

*The OP of this answer originally wrote: "I feel like a big dummy. Some more thorough searching turned up https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-missing-json-inspecto/hhffklcokfpbcajebmnpijpkaeadlgfn/related, which is exactly what I need." However, an edited version of this answer indicated that that extension was not open source and was no longer maintained.*

Comment: That extension is not open source, and hasn't been maintained since 2013. [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related) is actively maintained, better rated, and open source.

Comment: To help find a more active (or better rated) fork, you might want to try https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter

Comment: I also used this extension and it worked nice up to now. But recently Chrome contains it's own JSON formatting option which however has to be activated explicitly for each request which is quite cumbersome. Chromes JSON Formatter also visually conflicts with JSON Formatter which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a way with Chrome 97 and no plugins.

1. Visit a API or JSON resource in the URL
2. Open developer tools.  (F12)
3. Click the Source tab.
4. Open a source or hit CTRL-P
5. Select the JSON
6. In the top, select **Pretty Print**
7. You get nice JSON human-readable formatting!

Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you go to 'Network' instead you get an ever cleaner view in the 'Preview' tab

Comment: The pretty print option no longer seems to work?

Comment: @Protectorone when you open the file, click on `{}` at the bottom to pretty print the file. You can also preview the file from Network tab as @david-mulder mentioned but you will need to refresh the page if you went into developer tools after the page was loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and dislike the bloated-ware so I develop [Jipy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jipy/ijpoiflpbigbngjilejmkmnoglkedcjo)
It simply ask you to highlight (full or partial) JSON payload and trigger the format function. (hotkey, context-menu, or button)

Comment: Whoa, this is _really_ good. Makes viewing log files that are only partially valid JSON a breeze.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. An inline json formatter for Kibana logs! Thanks a lot!